# trying to understand Function.prototype.call in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var animals = [
  {species: 'Lion', name: 'King'},
  {species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function (i) { 
    this.print = function () { 
      console.log('#' + i  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name); 
    } 
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}

</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcall

Question:

1.why write this way: this.print, this.species, this.name? I tried to remove 'this', and in console log shows 'undefined'

2.`call(animals[i], i)` what is the difference between it and `call(this, i)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in reverse order...

(function()).call(...) sets the context in which the function is to execute. i.e. it sets the `this` object to the first argument. In your example the first version sets `this` to the element in the animals[] array. the second will set the context to whatever `this` is - here it will be the global context.

Once the context is set, your code can refer to it with the `this` keyword. In your first question `this` refers to the current animals[] element, so it can extract the species, name, etc. for each animal. Omitting the `this` keyword refers to variables in the global scope, which aren't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually created an Anonymous Constructor Function, which is what `this` is referring to when you made the Anonymous Constructor Function. Using `call(animals[i])` changes the context of `this` to each of the Object Literals inside of your `animals` Array as they pass through your loop.